# Trouble moving Drupal 6 installation to new domain name

Tags: drupal, migration, drupal-6, base-url

I need to change the domain name of an existing Drupal 6 installation.

The site is hosted on 1and1.com which allows you to map new domain names to existing directories, so I added the new domain name, selected the correct installation directory for it, and updated the $base_url in ...drupal/sites/settings.php.

This gave me the following error message:

> this is it! Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers
>   already sent by (output started at .../drupal/index.php:3) in
>   .../drupal/includes/common.inc on line 153

The database hasn't moved. The directory hasn't moved. So I'm thinking there must be other places that need to be updated with the new base url in order to function. Can't find an answer in the drupal documentation.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Something must be outputting text (probably an error) before common.inc modifies header info. Check your php error logs

Comment: does the error really contain `this is it!`? If so, you need to get rid of that. That is what would be causing the header error

Comment: If no code has changed, I am guessing on the old server you had `output_buffering` set to true which would hide this error.